# Compare dates form different time zones using timestamp

Tags: php

In my PHP application, I'm getting `HTTP POST` data from different timezones. I have a `from_date` field in the `POST` data where the user has to select a future date. I get values like '2021-04-13 08:00:00' in that field. I'm validating this data with the server time.

I'm converting the data and time to timestamp and verifying whether it's grated than server timestamp.

```
$_POST['from_date'] // '2021-04-13 08:00:00'

strtotime($_POST['from_date']) > time()
```

my server is in the European timezone, seems like this is not working.

My question is when we compare dates like this should I consider timezone also?

```
strtotime($_POST['from_date']) > (new DateTime("now", 'from_date_timezone'))->getTimestamp()
```

Comment: What timezone is `2021-04-13 08:00:00` in…? Without knowing that, you can't compare it to any absolute time at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When we compare dates like this should I consider timezone also?

Yes. Let's give a more "human" example:

> Is 2021-04-13 08:00:00 local time where I live before or after 2021-04-13 08:30:00 local time where you live?

We can't possibly answer that question without knowing the time zones for "where I live" and "where you live". Nor can PHP.

> Is 2021-04-13 08:00:00 local time where I live in the past or future?

There's only one time zone involved here ("local time where I live") but we still can't answer the question without knowing it.

```
strtotime($_POST['from_date']) > (new DateTime("now", 'from_date_timezone'))->getTimestamp()
```

This is a weird mix of object and integer based date handling. It's also logically backwards: "now" is the same point in time whatever time zone you're in, it's the *supplied* date you need to specify the time zone for.

Assuming `$_POST['from_date_timezone']` has a valid timezone, this should work:

```
$supplied_date_time = new DateTime($_POST['from_date'], new DateTimeZone($_POST['from_date_timezone']));
$now = new DateTime('now');
if ( $supplied_date_time <= $now ) {
    echo 'Supplied date-time is not in the future.';
}
```